# "Two-train" -- ein Zug mit zwei Elementen: Doppelzug? 2er-Zug? Andere Vorschläge?

Tags: english-to-german, single-word-request

Ich übersetze einen englischen Text, in dem die Rede ist von "two-train" -- es geht um "Züge von Funktionen", und ein "two-train" besteht aus genau zwei Funktionen.
Bzgl. "train" habe ich lange "Folge" favorisiert, mich dann aber doch für "Zug" entschieden, da das Wort ja auch im deutschen durchaus Folgen von Dingen beschreiben kann, die nichts mit der Eisenbahn zu tun haben ;)
Jetzt suche ich aber eine passende Übersetzung für "two-train" -- mir gefällt "Doppelzug" am Besten, aber vlt. gibt es sprachlich sinnvollere Möglichkeiten, die ich übersehe...

Comment: In welchem Kontext? Geht es hier um das Konzept von "function trains" in der Programmiersprache APL? Wenn ja ist mit two-train wohl ein 'train' mit zwei Glieder gemeint? Ein "Doppel-X" bezeichnet eine Zusammensetzung von zwei X und kein X mit zwei Teilen. Um in der Bahnwelt zu bleiben: Ein Doppelzug würde ich als zwei zusammengesetzte Züge interpretieren und nicht als ein Zug mit zwei Waggons, obwohl vielleicht das letztere vermutlich gemeint sein sollte.

Comment: Ohne zusätzliche Erklärung, was *Züge von Funktionen* sein sollen, kann man das m. E. nicht beantworten. Ich erinnere mich auch nicht, das schon je gelesen zu haben - es ist keine Komposition von Funktionen gemeint, wo die zweite Funktion das Ergebnis der ersten weiter verarbeitet?

Comment: Ach so, sowas hier? http://help.dyalog.com/14.1/Content/Language/Introduction/Trains.htm Ok, das bezieht sich ja nun recht klar auf Eisenbahnzüge, einfach weil die Syntax so aussieht, und es rechts immer eine "Lok" in Gestalt einer Funktion gibt. Würde ich dann wahrscheinlich mit "Zweierzügen" übersetzen. Kontext, Kontext, Kontext, und an die Leser denken ;-)

Comment: Oft ist es bei Fachvokabular sinnvoll, einen Anglizismus einzuführen, und in deinem Fall einfach auch im Deutschen von _two-trains_ zu sprechen.

Comment: Vielen Dank - es geht tatsächlich, wie mehrfach vermutet, um die APL-Trains! :) @jonathan.scholbach: das ist schwierig, da die Abgrenzung zu finden - ich möchte gerne, wo es sinnvoll und möglich ist, deutsch bleiben, damit die Texte nicht zu exotisch werden. Andererseits kann man das auch sehr gut erreichen, indem man zwanghaft eindeutscht und unpassende Terminologie verwendet ;) Ich nehme jetzt "Zweierzüge", werde das aber nochmal mit der dt. Community diskutieren, wenn ich noch andere Worte gesammelt habe.

Comment: Das Problem mit den Analogien ist, dass Eisenbahner auch ihre eigene Sprache haben... allgemein: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zug_(Schienenverkehr) Erstellung: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zugbildung Triebwagen: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zwillingstriebwagen Ist es also eher ein Triebwagen, dann wäre es Doppeltraktion. Ran und weg: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fl%C3%BCgelung Lokbespannte Züge - also die Analogie von hier - haben "hinten dran" einen Wagenpark. Und das ganze Ensemble heißt dann Zugkomposition. Und der Anhang sind meist Bei-, Trieb-, Mittel- oder Steuerwagen...

Comment: (und niemand hat dabei gefragt, ob "two-trains" überhaupt korrektes Eisenbahner-Englisch ist... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Train) (ist es nicht, war hier auch nicht die Frage ;-)

Comment: Stimmt, es ist anzunehmen, dass sich in der  über 50jährigen Geschichte von APL dazu eine Meinung der deutschen Community gebildet hat ... :-)

Comment: @HalvarF: die Züge gibt's in APL noch nicht so lange (2015)  ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sind die "two-trains" denn parallel oder sequentiell?

Linguee.com scheint two-train im Zusammenhang mit sowas wie Fabriken oder Werkstätten zu kennen, in denen es zwei parallel nutzbare Fließbänder oder sonstige Verarbeitungsanlagen gibt. Ist sowas gemeint? Oder eher ein (Eisenbahn-)Zug mit zwei Waggons?

Im ersten Fall würde ich vielleicht von zwei Strängen oder zwei Gleisen sprechen. In Schulen spricht man auch von mehreren "Klassenzügen", aber ich weiß nicht, wie verständlich das außerhalb dieses Kontexts ist.

Im zweiten Fall kämen alternativ vielleicht noch Doppelpack, Duo, Duett oder Tandem in Frage. Ohne mehr Kontext ist schwer zu beurteilen, ob die passen.

EDIT:

Nachdem @jambjo es in seinem Kommentar erwäht hat und im Profil des Fragestellern auch die Programmiersprache APL auftaucht, vermute ich, dass es wohl um das spezielle Konzept dieser Programmiersprache namens ""trains" geht: http://help.dyalog.com/14.1/Content/Language/Introduction/Trains.htm

Wenn man den Ausdruck überhaupt übersetzen möchte, kommt man m.E. kaum umhin, ihn als "Züge" zu übersetzen, weil sich der Ausdruck im Englischen wohl recht klar auf Eisenbahnzüge bezieht: zwei oder drei direkt hintereinanterstehende Ausdrücke in der Programmiersprache, der letzte davon ist immer eine Funktion (die man als Lok interpretieren könnte), und das Ganze bildet wieder eine Funktion.

Das würde ich dann wahrscheinlich mit "Zweierzüge" übersetzen, "Doppelzüge" ist vermutlich auch möglich oder besser, dazu weiß ich zu wenig über APL. In dem Link steht außerdem:

> The 3-item trains (f g h) and (A g h) are termed forks **while the 2-item train (g h) is termed an atop.**

... aber das wird jetzt wirklich offtopic.